# preg_replace with php code

Tags: php, parsing, preg-replace

I have a function that finds a regex thingy, then replaces with php code. I want to have it replace the found regex with php code on the screen, like have it echo out ". except when it echos that in the source, it shows all the `<?php` tags and echo and everything, and doesnt just output 'wat'. no im not going to just replace the text with the word 'wat' because that is not what im trying to do. do you know how to parse the php i replace it with?

```
$this->template = preg_replace("/<!-- IF (.*?)? ?-->/","<?php\nif($1) {",$this->template);
```

there is also and ENDIF which closes it with `} ?>`. the content in between is the output if the condition is true.

Comment: please, try to write and describe properly your problem, give examples where necessary

Comment: A code example and finishing that last sentence would help other to answer this.

Comment: Post your actual code, it will be useful to find the problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you need is eval() http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php